# How to test for argument name mismatches between HTML forms and ASP.NET MVC Controller Actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just found a bug where an HTML form element had a name like "fantastic" and the action had an argument like "f*tasktic." Since it was a checkbox, we were handling it being unchecked by coalescing to false (i.e., HTML forms submit no value for checkboxes that are unchecked, so we assumed null == unchecked.) Since the name was wrong, we always thought the element was unchecked.

This makes me realize that there are likely other places where we have problems like this.

Aside from writing exhaustive browser driven tests (such as with Selenium) are there any other good tricks for catching this type of error?

I am considering writing a test that looks in all of our spark views and asserts that for each argument in the action a form submits to, there is an HTML form element with the same name as the argument and vice versa. We have several "entire app" tests like this already, so it wouldn't be totally out of place, but it feels kind of brute force and I was wondering if anyone has a better way to catch this kind of thing.

Comment: interesting question,  i've done the same thing myself,  it's not always possible to use the templates and .editorFor  and some way to test for mis-matches would be handy!

Comment: @Patricia - It is always possible.  You just have to know how to customize the base object template to suit your needs.

Comment: Rather than testing you could ensure that if something is required then a value must be submitted, then when you get nothing submitted an error will be displayed. When rendering a checkbox MonoRail(?) used to render a hidden field with the false value so that something was always submitted for the field meaning no coalescing nulls to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a rule to always use ViewModels and EditorFor templates for to generate any form on the site.  This stops this problem dead in its tracks.

Brad Wilson has a great blog series on customizing the default template:  http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Just got put on a project where this isn't the case and I'm taken aback by the barbaric way in which we hand write html forms.  Icky!

Comment: Thanks @archil and @jfar, and especially thanks for the link @jfar.

Answer (score 0):

I use compile-time checks for my views and it negates my typos mistakes. Its not a strict view-to-object mapping test, but it is built in and solves typos (more so in my views than in my controllers).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use strongly typed ViewModels both when generating views and for the command arguments. This helps get rid of `strings` very much. Less handwriting input names and argument names - less mismatches between them